# how to use find command to get files created yesterday?

Tags: command-line, scripts, find, date

What is the option used with find to get files created yesterday on Linux scripting?

The below trials don't work:

```
find /log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/ -newer yesterday
```

OR

```
find -mtime 24

-----------------------------
the below command get files for today 10/10

[bssuser@t-bss-bill-app-01 Amany]$ find -newermt yesterday -ls
142619049    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 bssuser  bssuser      4096 Oct 10 08:40 .
142619072    4 -rwxrwxr-x   1 bssuser  bssuser      2376 Oct 10 08:40 ./test_am.sh
142619050    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 bssuser  bssuser       433 Oct 10 08:40 ./errors.csv
142619058    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 bssuser  bssuser       323 Oct 10 08:40 ./logs.csv
```

Comment: find /log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/ -cmin +1440 -type f -iname "*" -print

Comment: please would you clarify how this will fetch files created yesterday ? what about 1440?

Answer (score 5):

The `find` command's `-[acm]time` predicates are tricky.

In particular, `-mtime n` matches files whose modification time lies between `n` and `n+1` 24-hour periods before the *current time*. So

```
find . -mtime 1
```

will find files for the period between 24 and 48 hours before *now*. To find files relative to the calendar day, GNU `find` has the `-daystart` option, so to find files modified during the previous calendar day you can use

```
find . -daystart -mtime 1
```

See also:

- [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days)
- [What is the difference between "find . -daystart -mtime" and "find . -mtime"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709047/what-is-the-difference-between-find-daystart-mtime-and-find-mtime)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
find -newermt yesterday -ls
```

How it works, details from `man find`:

```
-newerXY reference
       Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being considered is newer than timestamp Y of the file reference.  The letters X and Y
       can be any of the following letters:

       a   The access time of the file reference
       B   The birth time of the file reference
       c   The inode status change time of reference
       m   The modification time of the file reference
       t   reference is interpreted directly as a time

       Some combinations are invalid; for example, it is invalid for X to be t.  Some combinations are  not  implemented  on  all
       systems;  for  example  B is not supported on all systems.  If an invalid or unsupported combination of XY is specified, a
       fatal error results.  Time specifications are interpreted as for the argument to the -d option of GNU date.  If you try to
       use  the  birth  time of a reference file, and the birth time cannot be determined, a fatal error message results.  If you
       specify a test which refers to the birth time of files being examined, this test will fail for any files where  the  birth
       time is unknown.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding files with the find command in Linux is tricky, but you can use the "`-ctime 1`" option to find files that were changed exactly 1 day ago. 
The find command to find files created yesterday will be:

```
find /path/to/search/directory -type f -newermt $(date -d yesterday '+%Y-%m-%d') ! -newermt $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
```

In this command:

- `/path/to/search/directory` is the directory where you want to start the search.
- `-type f` ensures that you are only looking for regular files.
- `-newermt $(date -d yesterday '+%Y-%m-%d')` specifies the modification time must be newer than yesterday.
- `! -newermt $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')` ensures that the modification time is not newer than today.

See Also:

- [35 Advance Examples of Find Command in Linux](https://linuxtldr.com/find-command/)
- [40 Best Examples of Find command in Linux](https://geekflare.com/linux-find-commands/)